# How do I stop Visual Studio from failing to build when projects include common libraries?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, dependencies

I have a visual studio solution whith (roughly speaking) the following layout:

```
Common.dll
Proja (project which references Common.dll)
Projb (project which references Common.dll)
Main (Executable which references proja and projb)
```

The problem is that sometimes when I compile I get

```
11>Proja : error PRJ0008 : Could not delete file 'c:\Blah blah blah\Main\Release\Ionic.Zip.dll'.
```

...because (I think) both proja and projb are being built at once. Since they both end up in the same output directory I'm guessing one thread attempts to delete the Common.dll while the other one is using it or something along those lines.

Now if it's just me compiling the project, that's fine as I can always hit the rebuild button and after a couple of fails it appears the sort itself out. The more difficult issue is that we're moving to using Jenkins and that keeps failing.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Hope it helps -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk8k8k4h(v=VS.80).aspx   See the community edit

Comment: You should post that as an answer so I can accept it. The bit that really helped was changing the intermediate and output directories to '$(ProjectDir)\$(ConfigurationName' for every single project.

Comment: Thanks Jon, but mine was only a link to a well documented analysis of your error message. I invite you to auto answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a bit of fiddling around, but the bit that seemed to sort the issue out in the end was changing the intermediate and output directory of every project to `$(ProjectDir)\$(ConfigurationName` seems to have solved the issue. I can run MSBuild with s many processors as I like and it still succeeds :-)

Answer (score 0):

From the Project menu,    Project Build Order, Project Dependencies Tab

This may help